# Bad Addressing in MIPS - Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, matrix, mips

A followup from my post yesterday,

I'm working on a matrix multiplication assignment in MIPS Assembly. The following is the code from my inner most 'k' loop where I compute A[i][k]*B[k][j].

```
    # compute A[i][k] address and load into $t3
    # A[i][k] = A+4*((4*i) + k)
    sll $t3, $t5, 2         # Store 4*i in $t3
    addu $t3, $t3, $t7       # Adds $t3 to k
    sll $t8, $t3, 2         # Computes 4*($t3) = 4*(4*i+k) by temporarily storing the product in $t8
    move $t3, $t8           # Stores 4*($t3) into $t3
    addu $t3, $t3, $a0       # Adds A to $t3
    lw $t3, 0($t3)

    # compute B[k][j] address and load into $t4
    # B[k][j] = B+4*((4*k) + j)
    sll $t4, $t7, 2          # Stores 4*k in $t4
    addu $t4, $t4, $t6       # Adds $t4 to j
    sll $t8, $t4, 2          # Computes 4*($t4) = 4*(4*k+j) by temporarily storing the product in $t8
    move $t4, $t8            # Stores 4*($t4) into $t4
    addu $t4, $t4, $a1       # Adds B to $t4
    lw $t4, 0($t4)

    # multiply

    multu $t3, $t4
    mflo $t9


    # insert the multiplied value into $a2
    sll $t1, $t5, 2          # Multiplies $t5 by 4 and stores the value in $t1
    addu $t1 $t1, $t6        # Adds $t1 and $t6 (j) for the final bit offset
    move $t2, $a2            # Stores $a2's base register in $t2 temporarily
    addu $a2, $a2, $t1       # Adds bit offset to $a2

    sw $t9, 0($a2)           # Store $t9 into its respective location in with offset from $a2

    move $a2, $t2            # Restores base address back into $a2

    # increment k and jump back or exit
    addi $t7, $t7, 1
    j kLoop
```

From what I can see, the multiplying works as it should. For reference, my $t5 - $t7 are for my i, j, and k.

My next step is to insert the result, stored in $t9, into my result array, situated at register $a2. In order to store $t9 at its proper location in $a2, I need to compute the offset. I know the offset is $a2 * the row + the column. However, when I run my code, I get Bad Addressing errors. I know something has to be wrong with this offset computation, because when I remove it, the program continues normally but there's an issue with my output. This issue stems from the lack of offset calculation. If anyone can help me out here, it would be much appreciated. Stackoverflow has helped me out so much with understanding MIPS, so I'm grateful for everyone's assistance! Thanks

Comment: Initial thought is you need to offset by i * sizeof(array_type) instead of just i, which would probably give bad alignment errors.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan That's what I was assuming was happening - should I attempt this with a sll?

Comment: Did you try to step over it in debugger? Or do you really believe it is easier for us to read the code, and run it in our heads? That `sw $t9, 0($t2)` ... if everything would work correctly, it should store the word at the same address, as the `lw $t1, 0($t1)` loads from? If yes, do you really want to calculate that address twice? And you have there some excessive usage of registers and moves, plus the comment looks to be a bit inaccurate then, as in `lw` part you operate with [i, j, k] (in comment I mean, not in code), in `sw` part only [i, j] is noted. You load `t1` and don't use it?

Comment: I mean, it's good that you at least do write those comments there, but try to reset your head, and read it after yourself, not in ordinary human re-read mode (as your brain will lie to you, reading what you did want to write there, instead of what is really written there), but try to re-read it as if you see it first time ever and don't know what it should do... then fix them to be clear and accurate. And the same thing about your mind playing tricks with you does apply also to code, even more. So make sure when looking for bug, you focus and read exactly what is written there, not your wish.

Comment: @Ped7g So I just updated my post with my most recent code and I'm still getting bad memory addresses. I stepped through it w the debugger (I'm using QtSpim) and it seems to abort when I do `sll $t1, $t5, 2`

Comment: @Ped7g but its strange because I'm using the right syntax for `sll`. $t5 gets shifted by 2^2 or 4 and that resulting address gets stored in $t1.

Comment: The `sll` itself can't abort on bad memory address (it's not referencing memory, only calculating with registers). Check the value in `t5` ahead of `sll`, if it makes sense, and after `sll` the `t1` should be `t5*4`. Maybe take note at the start, what are the initial addresses of matrices, and make sure the correct base values remain in `a2`, ..., and all the offsets are within ... your max size is 4x4 matrix? Then the legal offset is one of values: 0, 4, 8, ... , 15*4 = 60. (64 or more is beyond 4x4). I mean, it should be visible which number doesn't work as you need/expected.

Comment: You may also open the memory over `a, b, result` area, to see how the values evolve, maybe you will notice some problem there from the order of changing values in memory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156707/discussion-between-thunderbow98-and-ped7g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I wasn't calculating the bit offset properly - I wasn't multiplying the 4*i+j by 4 to get a multiple of 4 that can be addressed. After making that change, my multiplying part of my k loop now looks like this:

```
# multiply
multu $t3, $t4
mflo $t9


# insert the multiplied value into $a2
sll $t1, $t5, 2          # Multiplies $t5 (i) by 4 and stores the value in $t1
addu $t1 $t1, $t6        # Adds $t1 and $t6 (j) for the col offset
sll $t1, $t1, 2          # Multiplies $t1 by 4 and stores value back into $t1 for final bit offset
move $t2, $a2            # Stores $a2's base register in $t2 temporarily
addu $t2, $t2, $t1       # Adds bit offset to $t2 / $a2's temp alias


lw $t1, 0($t2)           # Overwrites $t1 with the value currently at $t2
addu $t9, $t9, $t1       # Adds the current $t2 val ($t1) to $t9

sw $t9, 0($t2)           # Store $t9 into its respective location in with offset from $a2
```

I figured I might as well share this with people so if anyone else has this issue, it can be resolved with relative ease. Thank you to everyone who assisted me with this problem!